# Textbox not sending entered value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following html in an aspx so it is already in a form:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have a button:-

```
<asp:Button ID="updateDetails" Text="Update Details" runat="server" OnClick="updateDetails_Click" />
```

In the code behind I have the `updateDetails_Click` proc:-

```
protected void updateDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    utils utils = new utils();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[utils.liveTest() + "arenadestinationsConnectionString"].ToString();

    string SQL = "UPDATE Users SET "
                + "Name = @Name, "                            
                + "WHERE IdUser = @iDUser";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iDUser", Session["loggedIn"].ToString());

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I type new text into the Name textbox, when I click on the Update Details button, the Name.Text always shows the original text, never the modified text.

What am I doing wrong? I'm converting myself from VB to C# so I will no doubt have a few tricks to learn.

Comment: Try storing the Value in a Session or Check ViewState if it's enabled also are you doing any `IsPostBack` checking Poor practice to leave out the `@` in the AddWithValues how do you think that Parameters are referenced / declared in SQL? with the `@`Symbol also Where is your SqlDataReader object?

Comment: Not doing any IsPostback checking. ViewState is enabled by default.

Comment: I believe that the provided answers below should answer / fix your issue you are responding a bit late to the previous question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update any records calling `ExecuteReader` as this is for SELECT statements (reading data). If you want to update the data in the DB, you must call `ExecuteNonQuery`

So change your code to:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Changed to command.ExecuteNonQuery(); Thanks. However, the data in the AddWithValue Name.Text is still the original from the page load. It's not picking up any changes typed into the box, which is the crux of the question really.

Comment: @Craig are you sure you are not resetting this value in Page_Load? Did you forget to add `if(!IsPostBack) \\set the contro's text` perhaps?

Comment: Icarus I love you!  The texts were being set BEFORE the button function ran. Many thanks. Hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
  command.ExecuteReader();
```

to

```
  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This is for insert, update, delete
```

and you can leave out the `@` in:

```
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", Name.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("iDUser", Session["loggedIn"].ToString());
```